# Looking for U2.NET Toolkit equivalent for FMT function

Tags: u2, unidata, u2netdk

In UniBasic, I can use the FMT function with a format spec like '30T', to insert Text Marks at appropriate places in a long string (think Remarks/Comments).  I don't see the equivalent in the U2.NET Toolkit.

I know I could create a UniBasic subroutine, and call it from C# - but I'd prefer not to.

Restatement of the core issue: in a SQL Server table, I have a text column (arbitrarily large, not a blob); I would like this to end up in a multi-valued field in a Unidata record, with MV marks every 30-ish characters (i.e., similar to 30T formatting).  To minimize server trips, I'd like it to be handled in C#.

I've seen various ways to handle word-wrap, so I can probably manage that - but first I'd like to make sure the formatting capabilities of Unidata aren't "hiding" somewhere in U2.NET Toolkit?

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you for asking this question. Could you please give me some idea? For example: C# Code (even it did not compile). What is your access mode : SQL or Native? We have function in U2Parameter Class called DataTable_To_MV(...), it creates MV with given Field Mark, Value Mark and DataTable. I need to understand your requirement.

Comment: In Current U2 Toolkit for .NET Release, we do not have this functionality (equivalent UniBASIC FMT) function. As you have noticed too, .NET Classes such as RegEx, String is more powerful than server side FMT function.

Comment: Rajan - you answered my question (no, there is not a U2.NET equivalent of the FMT function).  I've found some (hopefully) good examples of Word Wrap logic in C# that I'll be able to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this gets marked as answered, I'll repeat from the comments, above: no, the FMT function doesn't currently exist in U2.NET Toolkit.